# Sync Objects to changed parameters

Tags: javascript

I want to bind the parameters of an Object to another Object, so they update whenever the other one updates aswell.

```
Object1 =
  x: 1

Object2 =
  x: Object1.x
  y: 0
```

so that `Object1.x = 2;` updates `Object2` aswell. (And the other way round)

How do I do that efficiently? I could use `.watch` and update the other one on each change, but I doubt that is a smart solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you clarify how using the exact same shared object wouldn't suit your needs? Should behavior only apply to particular properties?

Comment: @apsillers I basically have 2 completely different objects, that I want to share the x-position with each other. So yes, the behavior should apply only to certain properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the environment this has to run, a getter might be a suitable solution:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object2, 'x', {
   get: function() {
     return Object1.x;
   },
   enumerable: true
});
```

You might also want to define a setter to sync changes back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the observer/observable pattern.

> I could use .watch and update the other one on each change, but I
>   doubt that is a smart solution

How you notify the other part if something changes? Why isn't a *smart solution*? It's just the solution!

Check this code listing I did to show you a possible implementation of objects capable of listening changes of other objects creating a base `ObservableObject` prototype [(also available in JSFiddle!)](http://jsfiddle.net/0L2oqz64/1/):

```
var ObservableObject = function () {
    this._handlers = [];
    this._disablePropertyChangeNotification = false;
};

ObservableObject.prototype = {
    get disablePropertyChangeNotification() {
        return this._disablePropertyChangeNotification;
    },

    set disablePropertyChangeNotification(value) {
        this._disablePropertyChangeNotification = value;
    },

    listenPropertyChange: function (handler) {
        this._handlers.push(handler);
    },

    notifyPropertyChange: function (propertyName) {
        if (!this.disablePropertyChangeNotification) {
            this._handlers.forEach(function (handler) {
                handler(propertyName);
            });
        }
    },
};

var A = function () {};
A.prototype = new ObservableObject();

Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, "name", {
    get: function () {
        return this._name;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        this._name = value;
        this.notifyPropertyChange("name");
    }
});

var B = function () {};
B.prototype = new ObservableObject();

Object.defineProperty(B.prototype, "name", {
    get: function () {
        return this._name;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        this._name = value;
        this.notifyPropertyChange("name");
    }
});

var someObjectA = new A();
var someObjectB = new B();

someObjectA.listenPropertyChange(function (propertyName) {
    // This will prevent an infinite loop where 
    // property from A is set by B and viceversa
    someObjectA.disablePropertyChangeNotification = true;
    someObjectB[propertyName] = someObjectA[propertyName];
    someObjectA.disablePropertyChangeNotification = false;
});

someObjectB.listenPropertyChange(function (propertyName) {
    // This will prevent an infinite loop where 
    // property from A is set by B and viceversa
    someObjectB.disablePropertyChangeNotification = true;
    someObjectA[propertyName] = someObjectB[propertyName];
    someObjectB.disablePropertyChangeNotification = false;
});

// We set name on A instance, and we print B instance name value
someObjectA.name = "hello world";
$(document.body).append("<p>someObjectB.name: " + someObjectB.name + "</p>");

// We set name on B instance, and we print A instance name value
someObjectB.name = "hello world changed";
$(document.body).append("<p>someObjectA.name: " + someObjectA.name + "</p>");
```